# What is "It is x o'clock" in Japanese with subject

Tags: grammar

I've just started studying Japanese so I'm using Hiragana.
In the book it says

> "It's 1 o'clock"

is

> "いちじです"

in Japanese. 
But if I want to use the form

> "X はいちじです"

then what should "X" be?

Comment: Hint: what does 'it' refer to in English?

Comment: I'm wondering if X could be 'いま'.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Most formally, we say:

> 「只今{ただいま}の時刻{じこく} + は + X時{じ}です。」

To continue roughly in the order of formality, we replace 「只今の時刻」 by:

> 「現在{げんざい}の時刻」
>
> 「今{いま}の時刻」
>
> 「今」

Please remember, however, that just saying 「X時です。」 is completely grammatical, normal, common, natural-sounding, etc. in Japanese.

Finally, by replacing the 「時刻{じこく}」 by 「時間{じかん}」 in the phrases above, they become slightly less formal as well.

Answer (score 1):

Japanese sometimes don't say subjects in daily conversations .
In Japan , people are needed to guess what other people mean or want to say . But in fact , we think it is polite and easy to understand to say subjects .

I think that too " Xじです " ( X is a number ) is a normal expression that we usually use .